# Msys shell has different Path variable than the host Windows system

Tags: c, windows, msys

I'm trying to install GTK and compile a C program with it on my Windows machine... Not an easy feat turns out.

Long story short, one of the steps of the process includes running `pkg-config` in the Msys shell. I have added the folder containing `pkg-config` to the system `PATH` variable (through the global control panel option, not through a local `SET`).

While `pkg-config` works in the regular Windows CMD prompt, running it in Msys results in bash: `pkg-config: command not found` error.

In the CMD, running `echo %PATH%` gives a different output than running `echo $PATH` in the Msys shell. The latter indeed doesn't show the folder containing `pkg-config`. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: MSYS2 has an option to import the system `PATH` at startup. Not sure if the original MSYS has it, but nothing stops you from modifying `PATH` from MSYS shell.

Comment: This may be a digression, but ... If you're using `win10`, you could enable "Windows Subsystem for Linux" [WSL] (provided by Microsoft--check settings/control panel), which uses a lightweight virtual machine that runs Ubuntu's linux kernel and all Ubuntu binaries will run unchanged. It's fairly easy/standard to install GTK under Ubuntu [or almost any linux distro]